# materialtable react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

использую react MaterialTable и не могу найти как сделать функцию скрытия столбца.

Заранее спасибо за пример.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=reactjs+MaterialTable+hide+column

Answer (score 0):

```
{ title: "Surname", field: "surname", hidden: true }
```

https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props

Surname column hidden:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-demo-forked-t1dqs?file=/demo.js:330-342